# WiFi Direct on iOS

Tags: ios, wifi-direct

I'm building an application connecting to a IoT device communicating via WifiDirect. Android connection is easy and straight forward. Is it possible with iOS 9 API to connect to a WiFi Direct or P2P networks while maintaining the Internet WiFi connection on and functioning?

There's very little information published about this, but I'm sure someone has done this before.

Thanks!
Ori

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "Multipeer Connectivity Framework" to create applications that will allow devices being in close distance to get connected, simply using Wi-Fi networks or Bluetooth.
As per the Apple doc there are three kinds of data that can be sent and received using the Multipeer Connectivity framework: Messages, Streaming,Resources

For more details: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity

Comment: Multipeer Connectivity Framework is compatible with iOS only, so you will not be able to create cross-platform connections.